# Local variables in parameters values

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Is it normal that local variables can't be used in place of `route_table_id` or in `resource names`? It seems to be working only with tags and where `name =` are used or am I not doing it correctly?

```
locals {
  public_subnet_name = "public_test"
  private_subnet_name = "private_test"
}

# Create Subnet
resource "aws_subnet" "public_test_a" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc_test_02.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/28"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  availability_zone = var.AZ[0]

  tags = {
    Name = "${local.public_subnet_name}_a"      # It works here
  }
}
```

But doesn't work in `route_able_id` or in resource names.

```
# Associate route table to subnets
resource "aws_route_table_association" "public_test_1" {        # can't replace public_test with local
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.public_test_a.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.public_test.id               # can't replace public_test with local
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "public_test_2" {        # can't replace public_test with local
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.public_test_b.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.public_test.id               # can't replace public_test with local
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That's why you should use [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#for_each-multiple-resource-instances-defined-by-a-map-or-set-of-strings) or [count](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#count-multiple-resource-instances-by-count) in cases like yours.

For example, you could define your public subnets as follows:

```
variable "public_cidr" {
  default = {
      public_test_1 = "10.0.0.0/24"
      public_test_2 = "10.0.2.0/24"
      public_test_3 = "10.0.4.0/24"
      }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public" {

  for_each          = var.public_cidr
  
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block        = each.value
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[0]
  
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  
  depends_on = [aws_internet_gateway.igw]
  
  tags = {
    Name = "public-${each.key}"
  }    
}
```

This way you could refer to the individual subnets as:

```
aws_subnet.public["public_test_1"]
aws_subnet.public["public_test_2"]
aws_subnet.public["public_test_3"]
```

Subsequently, your route table association could be:

```
resource "aws_route_table_association" "association" { 

  for_each  = aws_subnet.public

  subnet_id = each.value.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.rt.id      
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I'm asking the local variable I created `public_subnet_name ` can only be used in place of tags and why it doesn't work in the the place of resource name (`resource "aws_subnet" "public_test_a"`) and in the place of route_table_id value (`route_table_id = aws_route_table.public_test.id`). I'm only thinking of replacing the words `public test` using the variable I defined wherever possible. But it seems like it isn't allowed

Comment: @JohnDoe Because "aws_subnet" "public_test_a" are lables of `resource`. They are not expressions, where locals can only be used.

Comment: what about `route_table_id = aws_route_table.public_test.id`?

Comment: @JohnDoe I think that this is because you can access dynamically [attributes of resources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#indices-and-attributes), rather than their names. When you use `aws_route_table.public_test.id`, the `public_test` is `name`, not `attribute` of the resource as show in  [Accessing Resource Attributes](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html).